# How to update automatically?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am developing a report that will contain a small search field to send parameters, execute the query and show the data but I need that report to be updated every certain time or when there are more records to show, how could I auto update the report with the same parameters?

Answer (score 0):

You can add some timeout js function with location reload to reload the page every x minutes.
Example:

```
<script>
  setTimeout(function(){ document.location.reload() }, 300000);
</script>
```

Comment: @maximilian thanks for answering, it is possible that instead of reloading the entire page, it will only be reloaded by ajax and with the last parameters entered from a search engine?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can auto update the report page periodically using `timeout` and `ajax` request.

in your page.js

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  setTimeout(function(){ 
    $.ajax({
      url: '/report', # Write url of your request API
      type: "GET",
      data: data, # Pass data here, as a parameter
      dataType: "JSON",
    }).done(function(data) {
      # Do stuff here
    }
  }, 5000 ); # Set the time as you wish, this will execute at every 5 seconds
});
```

**Update ajax call**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  window.setInterval(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: '/report.js', # Write url of your request API
      type: "GET",
      data: data # Pass data here, as a parameter
    }).done(function(data) {
      # Do stuff here
    }
  }, 5000 ); # Set the time as you wish, this will execute at every 5 seconds
});
```

Comment: thanks for answering, I tried with your code but when I checked the console I see that it is not working, I need to place something more additional in my rails code to send it by ajax?

Comment: In the line data:data I get this error: Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined
    at

Comment: Data means pass your search params in hash format e.g. `data: {key: value, key: value}`

Comment: Well, now it is executed when the time lapse is fulfilled but it is only executed once, is there any way to make it run several times? and it is possible that instead of JSON it is executed by JS?

Comment: It will execute on every 5 second. and send request as js instead of json, check my updated answer.

Comment: thanks for the update, it is strange but it only reloads it once after the specified time, will it be because I am only loading specific parts of the page and not the whole page with the javascript code?

Comment: No problem, its not about load specific part of page, anyway I updated answer please check if it will work for you. and if you think it works for you accept the answer and up vote it.